# Grails 3.0.9 not updating object with MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, grails, grails-orm, gorm-mongodb, grails-3.0.9

I've problems updating a domain class. I'm using Grails 3.0.9 and MongoDB (for Gorm 5.0.0.RC1)

In my build.gradle:

```
compile "org.grails.plugins:mongodb:5.0.0.RC1"
compile "org.mongodb:mongodb-driver:3.0.2"
compile "org.grails:grails-datastore-gorm-mongodb:5.0.0.RC1"
runtime 'org.springframework.data:spring-data-mongodb:1.8.1.RELEASE'
compile("org.grails:gorm-mongodb-spring-boot:5.0.0.RC1")
```

The test:

```
@Integration
class CompanyControllerIntegrationSpec extends Specification{
def grailsApplication

Company company
RestBuilder rest

def setupData() {
    company = Company.buildWithoutSave().save(flush: true, failOnError: true) 

}

def setup(){
    rest = new RestBuilder()
} 


def "test update a company" (){
    def company2
    given:
        setupData()
        def id = company.id
    when:
        RestResponse response = rest.put("http://localhost:${grailsApplication.config.server.port}/${company.companyKey}/company") {
            json {
                name = "newName"
                description = "new Description"
            }
        }
        company2 = Company.findById(id)
    then:
        response.status == 200
        response.json.name == "newName"
        company2.name == "newName"
        company2.description == "new Description"
}
def cleanup() {
   Company.collection.remove(new BasicDBObject())
}

}}
```

The controller:

```
class CompanyController extends ExceptionController{

static allowedMethods = ['update':'PUT','show':'GET',
    'updateNew':'PUT','showNew':'GET']

CompanyService companyService

def update(String companyKey){

    def object = request.JSON?request.JSON:params
    Company companyOut = companyService.update(object, companyKey)

    render text:companyOut as JSON, status:HttpStatus.OK
}
}
```

The service:

```
class CompanyService {

def securityService
def grailsApplication

public Company update(object, String companyKey) throws ForbiddenException, InvalidRequestException, NotFoundException{
    Company company = findByKey(companyKey)
    if (object.name!=null)
        company.name = object.name
    if (object.description!=null)
        company.description = object.description
    if (object.enterprise!=null)
        company.enterprise = object.enterprise
    if (object.genKey!=null)
        company.companyKey = UUID.randomUUID().toString()

    if (!company.save(flush:true)){
        println company.errors
        throw new InvalidRequestException("Some parameters are missing or are invalid: "+company.errors.fieldErrors.field)
    }

    return company
}
public Company findByKey(String companyKey) throws NotFoundException, ForbiddenException {
    if (!companyKey){
        throw new ForbiddenException("The company key has not been given")
    }
    Company company = Company.findByCompanyKey(companyKey)
    if (!company){
        throw new NotFoundException("No company exists for the given key")
    }
    return company
}
}
```

The results of the test are:
- response.status is 200
- response.json.name is "newName"
- company.name is old name ("company 1")

If I don't do the cleanup, the database still have the old value. I've followed the save method, also inside Mongo gorm classes, and I've seen that one problem is that the fields are not being marked as dirty, but don't know why.
With other Domain classes that are similar to this one, the update is done without problems and the properties are marked as dirty.

Comment: What is `object` which you are passing to `update` method from the controller?

Comment: My fault with the cut&paste. Edited

Comment: Well, this seems to be working fine for me. If it's not an overhead, can you provide a small app reproducing this problem?